# c# how can i read text from tags in acrobat pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, tags, acrobat

How to extract text from the tags using c#?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any libraries currently to read PDF's already? 
I found this article that could get you started: 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/reading-contents-from-pdf-word-text-files-in-c-sharp1
It uses the iTextSharp Library. I'm not sure what other tools it has, but it can read PDF's.

Comment: Thank you, but I want the text from within the tag ...
 the text in tags may be incomplete or summarized from the text file

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tested it, something like this came to my mind. If it is not accepted, I can delete it.

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.Text;

namespace PDFExtractor
{
    public class PDFExtractor
    {
        public static string ExtractTextFromPDF(string pdfFileName)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            // Create a reader for the given PDF file
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFileName))
            {
                // Read pages
                for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    SimpleTextExtractionStrategy strategy =
                        new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                    string pageText =
                        PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);
                    result.Append(pageText);
                }
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string GetStrBetweenTags(string value, string startTag, string endTag)
    {
        if (value.Contains(startTag) && value.Contains(endTag))
        {
            int index = value.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
            return value.Substring(index, value.IndexOf(endTag) - index);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    // var str = GetStrBetweenTags(ExtractTextFromPDF("\path of PDf file\"), "<figure>", "</figure");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want the text from within the tag ...
 the text in tags may be incomplete or summarized from the text file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PdfPig](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig) to extract a page's marked contents and what they contain (text, images, paths and children):

```
using System;
using UglyToad.PdfPig;

[...]

using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Open("file.pdf"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < document.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        var page = document.GetPage(i + 1);
        var mcs = page.GetMarkedContents();

        foreach (var mc in mcs)
        {
            var letters = mc.Letters;
            var paths = mc.Paths;
            var images = mc.Images;

            foreach (var letter in letters)
            {
                Console.Write(letter.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```